# how to post a link on facebook use sdk PHP

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, laravel-5

i'm creating function to share a post to facebook and i'm following docs : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/postwithgraphapi. but it's not work.
This is my function

```
public function shareFB(Request $request, $slugify)
{
    $petition = Petitions::where('slug', $slugify)->first();
    $access_token = auth()->user()->social_account->access_token;

    $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
      'app_id' => config("services.facebook.client_id"),
      'app_secret' => config("services.facebook.client_secret"),
      'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
    ]);

    $linkData = [
      'link' => route('petitions.index',$petition->slug),
      'message' => $request->get('shareFB'),
    ];

    try {
        $response = $fb->post('/me/feed','post', $linkData, $access_token);
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
        echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }

    $share = $response->getGraphNode();
}
```

and here is my route in laravel

```
Route::post('share/p/{slugify}','Frontend\SocialController@shareFB')->name('social.shareFB');
```

When i clicked a button have href above, it's show  MethodNotAllowedHttpException . somebody help me solve that!!!

Comment: why not just use the share dialog instead? no publish_actions permission needed. you will most likely not get publish_actions approved just for sharing a link that can easily be done with the share dialog.

Comment: but it's not customize image and message from user :(

Comment: of course, the user can easily add the message in the dialog - prefilling would not be allowed anyway. and the image can be set with the og:image tag. you do not even set a custom image in your code at the moment.

Comment: Are you sure that you are POSTing to that route, not performing a GET request? Because that error suggests that you're using the wrong method.

Comment: when i use GET it's show try get non-object